# why a second reference to an object does not alter the content in java?

Tags: java, object, reference, instance

In the below code, I have created 3 instances of the Movie class. I have assigned some data to the three objects. Secondly, I have created a second reference to the object movie1(movie4). I have also assigned values to attributes of movie4.
I printed the new attributes of movie 1 **but the contents have not been altered**. Why does this happen? What is the exact reason? I know other ways of updating content but I want to know why the second referencing does'nt work.
The content is movie1 is still the same. Why ?

```
class Driver{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Movie movie1 = new Movie("The Shawshank Redemption", 1994, 9.3);
        Movie movie2 = new Movie("The Godfather", 1972, 9.2);
        Movie movie3 = new Movie("The Dark Knight", 2008, 9.0);

        **Movie movie4 = movie1;
        movie4 = new Movie("The Return of the King", 2003, 8.9);**

        movie4.name = "The Return of the King";
        movie4.year_of_release = 2003;
        movie4.rating = 8.9;
        System.out.println("\n*********New Movie 1 Details*************\n");
        movie1.printDetails();

    }
}
```

Comment: Because `movie4` does not point to `movie1` anymore. You're not modifying the object `movie4` points to, just *what* `movie4` points to.

Comment: can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Think of `movie1` and `movie4` as labels. You've just moved the `movie4` label to another object. That shouldn't change what `movie1` is still stuck to.

Comment: It is crucial for Java programming to understand that a variable is not an object, it is a thing that can refer to no more than one object at a time (or hold a primitive value, but that's beside the point here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This made `movie4` point to `movie1`:

```
Movie movie4 = movie1;
```

**but**, then you immediately updated `movie4` to point to a *different* object:

```
movie4 = new Movie("The Return of the King", 2003, 8.9);
```

So at that point, `movie1` and `movie4` are no longer pointing to the same `Movie`, so changes you make via `movie4` don't affect the object `movie1` points to.

If you had **changed** the object without replacing `movie4`:

```
Movie movie4 = movie1;
movie4.name = "The Return of the King";
```

...then you would have seen that change to the object whether you looked at `movie1.name` or `movie4.name`.

A bit more detail:

After you did this:

```
Movie movie1 = new Movie("The Shawshank Redemption", 1994, 9.3);
Movie movie2 = new Movie("The Godfather", 1972, 9.2);
Movie movie3 = new Movie("The Dark Knight", 2008, 9.0);
```

...you had something like this in memory (omitting a lot of details):

```
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie1:Ref4516−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Shawshank..." |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie2:Ref8469−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Godfather"    |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie3:Ref4789−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Dark Knight"  |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then you did this:

```
Movie movie4 = movie1;
```

...making `movie4` and `movie1` point to the same movie:

```
                  
movie1:Ref4516−−−+
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie4:Ref4516−−−+    | name: "The Shawshank..." |
                      | ...                      |                               
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie2:Ref8469−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Godfather"    |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie3:Ref4789−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Dark Knight"  |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So far, so good, but then you did:

```
movie4 = new Movie("The Return of the King", /*...*/);
```

...which made `movie4` point to a new object:

```
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie1:Ref4516−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Shawshank..." |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                 
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie2:Ref8469−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Godfather"    |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie3:Ref4789−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Dark Knight"  |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie4:Ref9546−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Return of..." |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So assigning to `movie4.name` just changes that new object, not the one that `movie1` points to.

If you **didn't** do that `movie4 = new Movie(/*...*/)` bit, so `movie1` and `movie4` still pointed at the same object

```
                  
movie1:Ref4516−−−+
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie4:Ref4516−−−+    | name: "The Shawshank..." |
                      | ...                      |                               
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie2:Ref8469−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Godfather"    |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie3:Ref4789−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Dark Knight"  |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...then assigning to `movie4.name` would change the object that both `movie4` and `movie1` are pointing at:

```
movie4.name = "The Return of the King";
```

```
                  
movie1:Ref4516−−−+
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie4:Ref4516−−−+    | name: "The Return of..." |
                      | ...                      |                               
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie2:Ref8469−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Godfather"    |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
movie3:Ref4789−−−−−−−>|         (Movie)          |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | name: "The Dark Knight"  |
                      | ...                      |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of this command

```
Movie movie4 = movie1;
```

The value of `movie4` is the reference to `movie1`, So the changes made on `movie4` would be reflected in `movie1` at this point.

```
movie4 = new Movie("The Return of the King", 2003, 8.9);
```

But after this command, `movie4` no longer holds the reference to `movie1`, its value is an entirely new reference. So any changes made are only made on the new object that `movie4` is pointing to not on the `movie1`